# How to create a timetable for school with models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Hi I'm new in Django and I want to create a web page that you can insert there a timetable of a school class, but I'm having a hard time to write the models for that task.
I made classes for a table, days and lessons, but I can't figure out how to not repeat information because every user can input as many time tables that they want, and every time table have the 7 weekdays, therefor I'll have the same day object more then once.

here my models:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Table(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique=True)


class Day(models.Model):
    # this spesific the table the those days belong to
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    # here we get this day lessons info in a list of dictionaris in a form of json
    lessons = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.table.name +' : ' + self.name

# here the class contain a lesson information
class Lesson(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'll be happy to hear a better way to create this data stracture.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Django problem, it's an architecture problem.

Here is an example of your data model:

```
Teacher
- id
- first_name
- last_name
- science_type (e.g. "math" or "computer science")

Lesson 
- id
- name
- teacher_id (FK on Teacher)
- duration (e.g. "60 minutes") 

TableDay
- id
- type (e.g. "Monday")

M2MLessonDay
- id
- lesson_id (FK on Lesson)
- day_id (FK on TableDay)
- start_time
```

This is how you can plan the same lessons without copying the same data many times. And the final table is the result from M2MLessonDay grouped by days and sorted by start_time.

Comment: but how do I implement M2MLessonDay as a class? if i have 30 hours of lessons in a week it means i make 30 objects of  M2MLessonDay ?

Comment: 1) Read about M2M-relation (in general and in Django). 2) Yes, correct